# HTML custom hover cursor pointer

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Goal**: I got certain svg circles in place, which are nodes from a D3 graph. I added a *darkmode* toggle and want to replace the default pointer cursor with an Xwing image. This should only be visible if I hover over an circle. All other elements are excluded.

**Problem:** I know how to change the cursor in general, like shown below, but I do not know how to change the cursor during an specific hover event. Any idea?

```
body {
    cursor: url("Xwing.png"), auto
}
```

Comment: what you mean by specific hover event? its a element based hover or js event

Comment: If I would hover over an circle element for example, I do not want the effect for all hover events. Like include circles and exclude buttons etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with [pseudo-class :not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

If you need to show the cursor image to all use `body or *` instead of `.circle`

**updated** for toggle

```
.circle:not(.excludedClassName) {
  cursor: url("Xwing.png"), auto
}

/*disabled if dark class match*/
.dark .circle:not(.excludedClassName) { 
  cursor: pointer !important; /* it will overwrite the cursor*/
}
```

Comment: Got you but how can I enable / disable this with with the help of a toggle? For example if darkmode disabled, cursor: pointer else if darkmode enabled cursor: url(Xwing.png), auto

Comment: you will control based on global parent component class. Check my updated answer